# Toggle checkboxes with jQuery

Tags: jquery, checkbox, toggle

I have a form with a random number of checkboxes.  I' trying to toggle them on/off via jquery when the top one is checked/un-checked **BUT skip any checkboxes that are disabled.**  The first checkbox has an id of "select_all" and the jquery is shown below. This works fine the FIRST time, but all subsequent attempts fail. I don't see any errors in Chrome's console.  Any ideas?  I don't care if I use this code or something else.

```
<script>
    $('#select_all').click(function() {
        var c = this.checked;
        if(c == true){
            $('input:checkbox:not(:disabled)').attr('checked','checked');
        } else {
            $('input:checkbox:not(:disabled)').removeAttr('checked');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: instead of `attr` use `prop` give this a try

Comment: `$('#select_all').click(function() {
  $('input:checkbox:not(:disabled)').prop('checked', this.checked);
});`

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
var c = this.checked;
```

For this

```
var c = $(this).prop('checked');
```

And your if condition to something like:

```
If(typeof c !== 'undefined')
```